# WooCommerce custom permalink structure causing problems

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've encountered a huge problem. I've changes my WooCommerce permalinks to this structure here:

```
/shop/kategorie/subcategory
```

When I now click on a category I'm getting a 404 issue. Do you know why? Before I did this my structure was:

```
/kategorie/subcategory
```

With this all worked fine but I want to make the domain look better with the whole path.

My custom category base:

```
/shop/kategorie
```

My custom product base is now:

```
/shop/kategorie/%product_cat%/%post_id%/
```

So is there any solution to fix this issue?

**Update**

I forgot to say, that when I open a product by directly, without the step going thru the subcategory, all works fine and the URL is correct as well.

Comment: Instead of using "shop" in your permalink structure, you could just use the product category structure for your products using [woocommerce permalink manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-permalink-manager/) plugin.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thats not a solution. It destroyed my whole structure so I've removed it.